# Рефлексия в наследовании

Tags: .net

Привет всем!
Возник спор, помогите прояснить.
В .NET использует ли рефлексию механизм наследования?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рефлексия подразумевает доступ к данным в процессе выполнения программы. Наследование используется в процессе копмиляции кода в байт-код. Конкретная реализация механизма наследования зависит от плаформы и версии компилятора. Но по сути наследование подразумевает, что наследник имеет ссылку на своего родителя, а дальше уже компилятор проверяет не нарушет ли код правила спецификации. Например, если мы создадим новый метод, то не будет ли у него такого же названия как и у финального метода предка.

Наследование вы можете увидеть в байт-коде. Рефлексия совершает изменения "на лету". Да и вообще, рефлексия - это обычно довольно дорогой процесс (по времени).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, хотел бы кое-что уточнить
допустим есть класс A от него наследуется класс B, объявляем ссылку типа A и записываем в нее обобьет B, участвует ли в этом процессе рефлексия?

Comment: @kotki Рефлексия - это просто инструмент. Он не работает где-то за сценой (если не считать реализацию некоторых фреймворков). Вы можете это сделать через рефлексию, но без прикладывания каких-то особых усилий она сама не сработает.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: Наверное не рефлексия совершает изменения, а конкретно генератор классов, у меня к примеру 99% "рефлексии" используется что б опросить обьект. Из всей Reflection только ветка Emit позволяет генерировать классы, и то делает это не сама, а с помощью дополнительной native-dll.

Answer (score 4):

Рефлексия - это способ опрашивать получать информацию об обьекте или классе с помощью, например, библиотеки System.Reflection.

Наследование - это способность создавать одни обьекты на базе других наследуя их поведение/свойства.
  Если вдаваться в подробности, то наследование делается с помощью компилятора. Механизм реализующий это достаточно сложный. 
 Ещё, в Библиотеке  System.Reflection есть отдельный генератор, который позволяет создавать классы, наследуя, другие классы, но назвать его рефлексией будет не совсем верно.

<strike>Для ответа да или нет - вам нужно "раскрыть" "механизм", и заглянуть вовнутрь какие классы он использует, и использует ли он эту библиотеку напрямую. Я думаю что нет.</strike>
Всё таки наследование это абстрактное понятие, а механизм - что называть механизмом? IL-код или компилятор или генератор? Непосредственно наследование делается с помощью двоичного кода - структуры - набор ссылок в памяти который позволяет с помощью нескольких разнородных участков памяти собрать/представить один целый обьект.

Comment: неплохой же ответ был

Comment: Я пришёл к выводу что нужно уточнить в вопросе какой из механизмов имеется ввиду. Их похоже что несколько.

Comment: Спасибо что прояснил

Answer (score 2):

Рефлексию можно было бы использовать для имитации наследования в рантайме на основе DynamicObject (подозреваю, что в ограниченном виде). Однако очевидно, что компилятор всё наследование обрабатывает ещё при компиляции и необходимости взаимодействовать с ним в рантайме через рефлексию нет.

Вызовы виртуальных методов делаются через таблицы соответствия. На каждый вызов метода проверять цепочки наследования через рефлексию было бы очень накладно, поэтому так не делается.